# Core Data - Fetch last objects of an array of objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

Using below code, I am fetching an array of emails from Core Data. I pass an array of emailId as the predicate to the fetch and it returns all emails for each of the emailIds.

However, I only need last object (or last email) of each of the emailIds in the predicate. Currently, I take the output of this fetch and use separate sorting to filter the objects I want. However, I would like the filtering in this fetch itself. Is there any way to do that?

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)getLatestEmail:(NSArray *)emailId
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email_id IN %@", emailId];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Emails"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"last_update_timestamp" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                                             initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                             managedObjectContext:self.context
                                                             sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                             cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.emailFetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.emailFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"getLatestEmail failed %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

        NSArray *emails = [[self.context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];


    return _emailFetchedResultsController;
}
```

I tried adding `.lastobject` to `[[self.context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy]`, but didn't work. I couldn't also find any documentation that suggests that this is possible. However, I am sure, someone would have tried it before and would like to hear their opinion.

Comment: I don't think you can do with with core data. you are better off taking the returned set and using an @max predicate. look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html

Comment: I may be way off here, but if you can get the first record with say emails[0], wouldn't the last record be emails[-1]. That seems to work in several programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Invert your sort descriptor, then just set the batch size to 1 and the offset to zero.